# Find all of the level sets of $f(x,y,z)=\frac{\left |(x,y,z)\times \vec{v} \right |}{\left |(x,y,z) \right |}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $0\neq \vec{v}\in \mathbb{R}$ a constant vector.
For every $(x,y,z)\neq 0$ let $f(x,y,z)=\frac{\left |(x,y,z)\times \vec{v}  \right |}{\left |(x,y,z)  \right |}$.
Find all of the level sets of $f$. Are there between all of the level sets a plane and a line which make a $90^{\circ}$ angle?

I have no idea how I should solve this question, i tryed setting $\vec{v}=(a,b,c)$ and opening the cross multiplaction but nothing seems to work.
I also tryed setting it like that $f(x,y,z)= \left | \vec{v} \right |* \left | sin(\alpha ) \right |$ but this gets me nowhere because i cant find a connection with alpha.

Anybody has any hints on how to attack this question because i currently have no idea.

Comment: Hint: From $f(x,y,z)= \left | \vec{v} \right |* \left | sin(\alpha ) \right |$, since $\vec{v}$ is constant, what can you say about what set of $(x,y,z)$ give some particular value? For example, try starting with $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I already tryed to attack the question in this way and it go me nowhere. But, maybe i dont understand what this hint says.

Comment: If two vectors $\vec{x}_1$ and $\vec{x}_2$ make the same angle with $\vec{v}$, what can you say about $f(\vec{x}_1)$ and $f(\vec{x}_2)$?

Comment: It means they have the same unit vector due I have no idea still on what should I do. could you please write a full answer when you have time

Comment: I won't write a full answer, because this seems to be a homework problem. But with $f(x,y,z) = |\vec{v}|\cdot|\sin\alpha|$, since $\vec{v}$ is a given constant, if $\vec{x_1}$ and $\vec{x_2}$ make the same angle $\alpha$ with $\vec{v}$, then $f(\vec{x_1}) = |\vec{v}|\cdot|\sin\alpha| = f(\vec{x_2})$.

Comment: So I get a half circle which repites itself infinite amount of times with a radius of length vector v. Therefore any vector which would have the same unit vector, will create the same angle with v. I understood you right?

Comment: So I got an empty set for c < 0, c=0 a line, and for any from c to a vector the size of v a cone. Am I right?

Comment: Almost. Since $\vec{v}\ne 0$, for any value of $v$ the level sets are cones consisting of all vectors $\vec{x}$ that make a fixed angle with $\vec{v}$. It doesn't really matter if $c<0$ or $c=0$ (there's nothing special about $c$ as a coordinate, right? The problem is symmetric, so why didn't you say "for $a<0$", for example?)